# I keep get the same error everytime I compile a C++ code with VScode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I made some code a long time ago that actually worked, but recently when I try to compile it with VScode, this error keeps showing up even when I delete all the modification i did:

```
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 22
+ g++ main.cpp -o main && main
+                      ~~
Le jeton « && » n’est pas un séparateur d’instruction valide.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

Sorry, my computer is actually in French so the error also.
Is someone does have the same error and know the answer?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: ```#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include "Guerrier.cpp" 
//#include "Mage.cpp"
//#include "Personnage.cpp"

using namespace std;

#include "fonction.cpp"

#include "pion.cpp"


int main()
{
    
   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `g++ main.cpp -o main && main` and how are you running it?

Comment: he is actually in a Google drive connected file and I run it with VScode compiler

Comment: Why are you using the `&&` in the command line?  In my experience, more cases fail the compilation and so won't be executed.  In Visual Studio, there is the "build" command and the "run" command, separate operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a [bug in VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87967). Install a fixed version and try again.

Comment: It's the fist time I get the good answer in such a short time, thanks a lot !

Comment: Switch it to English and you get better search resuts.